# Where to specify the appId and appSecret for Facebook login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Every time there is a new version of .NET Framework, the framework for authentication using external logins is overhauled!

The external login documentation link for MVC 6, http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715, is missing.

The initialization now uses `IApplicationBuilder` instead of `IAppBuilder` in the previous version. The `useFacebookAuthentication` method now does not take `appId` and `appSecret` parameters. How do I specify these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `project.json` file, in the `dependencies` section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Then, in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Other code here

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = "";
        options.AppSecret = "";
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Further up in Startup.cs in the `ConfigureServices` method, there is a `services.Configure<FacebookAuthenticationOptions>` method call.  What does this do?

Comment: @OldGeezer - that was used in an older version of asp.net5, it got replaced in Beta 8. Have a look here: http://wildermuth.com/2015/10/20/Upgrading_from_ASP_NET_5_Beta_7_to_Beta_8

Comment: I have just installed Update 1 and now the `app` object does not have those `UseXXXXAuthenticaion` methods! What am I missing?

Comment: @OldGeezer - did you add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook"` to your `project.json` dependencies section?

Comment: I can't find this under Add References.  Do I have to NuGet like in the previous edition?

Comment: @OldGeezer - No, not for this. Find the `project.json` file in the root of your project and open that file. Add the reference into this file in the `dependencies` section.

Comment: I thought `Add References` does that for me? If I add manually, I wouldn't know the exact version number or how to find and add in the required DLL. But I did what you said and magically, `UseFacebookAuthentication` becomes a method to `IAplicationBuilder`. I don't know what is going on.

The template code has: // To configure external authentication please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715, but the linked article (now no more 404) refers to a very old beta.

Comment: @OldGeezer You get intellisense prompts when you start typing in the dependencies section. Give it a try :)